# How to stop my app from populating S3 Staging Directory during startup?

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-jdbc, amazon-athena, hikaricp, anypoint-studio

I am using MuleSoft's Anypoint Studio to launch a simple app which queries csv files stored in S3 by using AWS Athena. For connection I'm using HikariCP.

Every time during app startup, 20 files are being created at the Staging Directory (10 .txt + .metadata pairs).

Every .txt's content is the same, being a list of Athena Databases, like this:

```
default
testDB1
testDB2
```

...and corresponding .metadata contains a long string of chars.

I don't want them to appear there. Although being small in size, they clutter up the folder .

Is there a way to stop those files from being spawned?

**Edit:**

Answers and comments pointed me to the right direction. After some digging, I found out what may be the cause of the problem.

Turns out, my app queries SHOW SCHEMA every few seconds (!). That's what racks up the numerous logs.

Is there a way to make those less frequent?

here is my flow.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" 
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring/current/mule-spring.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
      

    <spring:config name="springConfig" files="connection-factory-beans.xml"/>

    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="5c7a11f9-8834-4b0d-8c89-20e31b1efb5e" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="496b4171-4c51-425c-a7a4-875573869b77" >
        <db:data-source-connection dataSourceRef="dataSource" />
    </db:config>
    <flow name="athenaflowFlow" doc:id="31c54471-6732-4713-b77c-2b0bc97569eb" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="b7310b2b-ad53-4496-a838-fa208f71bbce" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/athena"/>

        <db:select doc:name="Select" doc:id="0817b143-4824-4da3-962f-bacf67bbb06c" config-ref="Database_Config">
            <db:sql ><![CDATA[SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mytestdb"."tabel1"]]></db:sql>
        </db:select>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="2745d5b0-6028-40a9-bcef-994acd287364" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="d6706d4e-3970-4f8b-b503-78229b32bf0f" message="#[payload]" />

    
</flow>
</mule>
```

And here is my connection-factory-beans.xml:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">


  <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
     <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:awsathena://athena.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443"/>
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver"/>
     <property name="dataSourceProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="s3_staging_dir">s3://my-bucket/my-staging-dir/</prop>
        <prop key="log_level">INFO</prop>   
        <prop key="region_name">eu-central-1</prop>   
        <prop key="user">myusername</prop>
        <prop key="password">mypasswd</prop>   
     </props>
     </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">  
     <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />  
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Is there something in your application creating the files? what versions do you use (Mule, connectors)? What is the staging directory?

Comment: @aled My app creates no files (that I know of). Mule version is 4.3. Mule Agent Version is 2.4.6. It's a simple Database Select that connects to AWS by datasource connection. Athena connector is AthenaJDBC42_2.0.9. Datasource connection based on it uses Hikari. That's how it connects to Athena.
Staging directory is a folder in a bucket on S3.

Comment: It has to be something that the application is doing. Mule would not write anything to S3 by itself.

Comment: Could you share the XML of the flow that sends files to Athena?

Comment: @aled - I edited the post - added XMLs

Answer (score 0):

These files are the results of running Athena queries. [.txt files and corresponding .txt.metadata files are written in the result output directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html) after operations like creating tables and views have completed.

Where these files appear depends on the output location configuration. This can be configured on the work group, and in each query. [You can set workgroup settings to override client settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/workgroups-settings-override.html), otherwise client settings override workgroup settings.

You can't stop these files from being created, but you can configure things so that they are created somewhere else, where they are not in the way. I don't know how your setup is configured, but since you're using the JDBC driver you can look in the [JDBC Driver Installation and Configuration guide](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.9/docs/Simba+Athena+JDBC+Driver+Install+and+Configuration+Guide.pdf) for "S3OutputLocation".

Answer (score 0):

The files that you see in s3 staging directory are the results of your queries as pointed out by Theo.

I also see a select statement in your flow.xml which also create files for executing this.If you really don't need it then you can remove this entry and follow a simple config as explained in [this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-To-Connect-to-AWS-Athena-Database-in-a-Mule-Application-with-Generic-Database-Configuration).

The SHOW SCHEMA queries that you see in Athena history section are the result of every refresh/browsing the databases/tables in MuleSoft's Anypoint Studio. If you want to verify the same just connect to Athena and be idle for some time and check if there are any queries executed in Athena history section.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having similar issue:

My problem was the size of HikariCP connection pool. By default it's 10.

Every new connection (and the pool seems refresh every 30 minutes) results in two files being created.

By setting the maximumPoolSize in Hikari to a smaller value, the amount of SHOW SCHEMAS calls decreased (thus saving the rest of my monthly quota on AWS).